# Usar solo el año en django model DateField

Tags: python, django, django-models

En este momento me gustaría mostrar agarrar el año del campo DateField o que se pueda escoger de alguna manera en el admin. Lo que no quiero es día y mes, porque solamente me interesa el año. Creo que no hay un YearField, para este tipo de situaciones.

Estaba intentando esta solución https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1517474/only-showing-year-in-django-admin-a-yearfield-instead-of-datefield pero tengo me da un error al decir que `NameError: name '_' is not defined` y en otra ocasión me ha dado `TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (2 given)`

Si alguien puede ayudarme lo agradeceré

Answer (score 2, accepted):

para solucionarlo necesitas hacer lo siguiente:

> 1. Tu campo puede ser DateField o DateTimeField.

```
timestamp = models.DateField()
```

> 2. Dentro de tu modelo Django crear un property como este:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    timestamp = models.DateField()

    @property
    def only_year(self):
        return self.timestamp.strftime('%Y')
```

> 3. En tu archivo admin.py, en el ModelAdmin debes agregar este property en tu list_display:

```
@admin.register(MyModel)
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ("name", "timestamp", "only_year")
```

Esto permitirá que en la tabla que te genera el admin Django se visualice solamente el año en lugar de toda la fecha.

Comment: Y puedo hacer que el DateField me permita guarda solamente el año y no toda la fecha?

Comment: Si necesitas solamente almacenar la información del año entonces te recomendaría utilizar un IntegerField porque el campo DateField o DateTimeField no tiene esa capacidad, a menos que siempre le envíes mes 1 día 1 para completar el objeto tipo fecha.

Answer (score 1):

La forma más simple es solo cuestión de presentación:

Crea el campo como DateField y cuando lo presentes **muestra** solo el  año.

```
year.strftime('%Y')
{{ year|date: "Y" }}
```

La otra opción es que guardes solo el año, pero perderías todas las funcionalidades que ofrece el módulo `datetime` para tratamiento de fechas.

Comment: Pero en el admin puedo mostrarlo solo de esa manera? no que se muestre "1954 Dec 17" si no solamente 1954? Puedo colocar esa primera linea que colocas dentro del DateField?

Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes generar un campo DropDown también así:

En tu models.py

```
from django.db import models
import datetime

YEAR_CHOICES = []
for r in range(1980, (datetime.datetime.now().year+1)):
YEAR_CHOICES.append((r,r))
```

Y así puedes ocupar YEAR_CHOICES en tu campo así:

```
year = models.IntegerField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES,default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
```